# How do you develop/deploy spring surf applications in java

Tags: spring

I'm looking for an example Spring surf web app that I can easily:

Setup as a project in Eclipse
Deploy to a local app server

Answer (score 0):

Look here, you can use `Roo` and start within a minute http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.M2/spring-surf-devtools/spring-surf-roo-addon/reference/html/beginning.html

Comment: please give me an example and how to down load spring surf

Comment: i created a directory according to given link 2.3.1 but i am not getting installation please help me it is very important to me thank u

Comment: Use `SpringToolSuite` IDE.

Comment: please give me a suggestion how to use SpringToolSuite,give me simple example code

Comment: It is an IDE. Just download and install it. It have wizards to help you out.